# solspace rating, never displays "name", "screen_name", "fullname" tied with rating

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

The following NEVER displays a name, how can I get it to output a name? Here is what I have:

```
{exp:rating:entries
    limit="10"
    entry_id="{embed:the_entry_id}"}

    <h4>{if screen_name}
            {screen_name}
        {if:elseif fullname}
            {fullname}
        {if:elseif name}
            {name}
        {/if}</h4>
{/exp:rating:entries}
```

This is the form I am using, which does actually save the name in the ratings module within the backend.

```
{exp:rating:form
    entry_id="{embed:the_entry_id}"
    collection="Products"
    return="product/thanks"
    form:class="form validate"
    status="closed"
    anonymous="yes"
    allow_duplicates="no"}

    <input type="text" name="name" value="{name}" class="required" />
{/exp:rating:form}
```

I heard somewhere deleting the name field, then recreating it with the same name seemed to fix it, though I've not experienced that myself.

Comment: Could you edit your question and actually include a clear question?

Comment: Done, though thought my objective was pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a limit if you are explicitly setting one entry_id.
2nd, have you turned on template debug to check that you are getting the values correctly passed to your embed?
3rd, try eliminating the conditionals, and just leave all 3 variables and see what you get back.
4th, make sure you have submitted some ratings for that entry. :-}

Also go to tools/data/sql manager and look at the exp_ratings table and see what your data looks like. i. e. was a name saved?

Comment: 1.I do want to keep the limit though I'm guessing doesn't matter.
2.I'll try template debugging and get back to you.
3. I'll let you know
4. there are plenty saved!
5. names are saved in exp_ratings table

Comment: 2. template debugging did not show anything suspicious, 3. tried that all the variables returned nothing.

Figured out a fix and added as another answer.

Comment: 2. Did Template Debugging show `entry_id="{embed:the_entry_id}"`, `entry_id=""` or `entry_id="123"` (123 would be the channel entry_id)? 3. Did you write the following as-is, without conditionals: `{name}|{screen_name}|{fullname}`, and got no output from it?

Answer (score 0):

No idea why its broken, still a mystery to me, though here is what I did to fix.

In my initial template create an embed and pass it the rating_id :

```
{embed="product/.testimonial_name" the_rating_id="{rating_id}"}
```

Then in that:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT name FROM exp_ratings WHERE rating_id='{embed:the_rating_id}'"}
    {if name}
        <h4>{name}</h4>
    {/if}
{/exp:query}
```